# Endomorphism rings of commutative algebraic groups are Noetherian?

Tags: ring-theory, abelian-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth connected commutative algebraic group over an algebraic closed field $K$. Is it true that its ring of endomorphisms (in the category of algebraic groups), denoted End($X$), always (left or right) Noetherian?

It is well known that if $X$ is an abelian variety then End($X$) is a free abelian group of finite rank. It follows that End($X$) is Noetherian as a ring.

If $X$ is a connected commutative complex linear algebraic group then $X\simeq \mathbb{G}_a^r \times \mathbb{G}_m^s$ for some $r,s \in \mathbb{N}$. 
Using this, we can see that End$(X)$ is also a Noetherian ring.

What about the general case? 
Can we use Chevalley's structure theorem for algebraic groups to say something about End($X$)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what "endomorphisms of algebraic groups" means, totally. Does the ring of linear transformations of $\oplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb C$ count? Or is that a "complex linear algebraic group"? I would be interesting in knowing what prevents the ring of linear transformations from being what you ask for.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm pretty sure it's just the algebra of homomorphisms $G \to G$ where addition is given by the group law on $G$ and multiplication is composition